# SVG и JS - SVG не поддается динамическому изменению атрибутов элемента.

Tags: svg, javascript

Думаю, все знают, что есть такой сервис как Gmaps. Думаю, что некоторые пользовали его API. Так вот, у них есть бага с SVG графикой при отрисовке геозон, которое, я понимаю, как исправить (написал рабочую формулу расчета).  Ладно, дело не в этом. Сел я изучать SVG графику и принципы ее отрисовки.  Вроде бы разобрался. Далее, я статически нарисовал кружок и с помощью JS-а пытаюсь поменять его атрибуты.

Например:

Отрывок кода круга

```
<circle id="cRed" onClick="this.cx.animVal.value = o.test(this);" cx="200px" cy="200px" r="104px" fill="red"   transform="translate(  0,-52)" />
```

Отрывок JS кода

```
MyClass.prototype.test = function(v){
    p = v.cx.animVal.value;
    return this.p = p+10;
};
```

Если трэйсить вывод функции, то результат возвращается правильный (в нашем случае - 210). Но! Не выполняется конструкция:

```
onClick="this.cx.animVal.value = o.test(this);"
```

По итогу получаем ошибку:

> `Modifications are not allowed for this document`

Что свидетельствует о том, что нельзя странице с помощью JS менять атрибут этого элемента. Вопрос: почему и как можно добиться динамического изменения атрибутов элемента без его полной перерисовки?

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, а что Вы читали по SVG? Порекомендуйте. 

Comment: Элла, исключительно Википедию.
А в чем вопрос ? Задавай, я теперь уже этот SVG вдоль и поперек изучил :D

Comment: Спасибо. Тут задача -сделать такое приложение для садоводов-огородников. Сначала простыми геометрическими элементами пользователь размечает участок в масштабе, делит на грядки (допустим, они бывают не только прямоугольными). Потом там идет история-что было посеяно в предыдущие сезоны (есть определенная последовательность что после чего можно сажать-сеять), исходя из последовательности выбирают, что посеют в этот сезон. Потом подбирают из базы данных семена, и из площади грядок вычисляют сколько этих семян нужно. Ну и еще на основе видов этих семян и календаря огородников высылают время от врем

Comment: Элла, думаю, что тут проще воспользоваться стандартными средствами, которые уже описали до нас :) Впринципе да, если с самого нуля писанину писать - SVG, + JS.
Проще копать в сторону API картографических ресурсов типа GMAP, Yandex и т.д. Там все проще с масштабами, координатами => будет более точно :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ура, вопрос можно считать закрытым. Для начала я покопал атрибутику элемента SVG, и нашел такой метод как setAttribute. Собственно

```
param.setAttribute("r", this.r) // Добавил атрибут радиуса и указал его размер, который храниться в this.r
```

Далее этот атрибут можно менять сколько угодно раз без особых усилий :) Спаcибо мне :)